# Spring implicit constructor injection not working in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I'm developing a web app using Spring (5.2.6.RELEASE), Tomcat (8.5.29), and Apache CXF (3.3.6). Spring's implicit constructor injection works fine in my integration tests (using JUnit 4.13), but when I deploy the web app to a live Tomcat server, I get error messages like the following:

```
[...] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'foo.bar.UserService#35fa8149' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [foo.bar.UserService]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: foo.bar.UserService.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [foo.bar.UserService]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: foo.bar.UserService.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: foo.bar.UserService.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 30 more
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm not using the @Autowired annotation in any of my code, but it is used in the integration-test code - could that be making a difference?

**Edit: Here are the "production" and "integration test" context XML files:**

"Production":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">
  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="environment">
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    [...]
  </bean>
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    [...]
  </bean>
  <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="true">
    [...]
  </jdbc:initialize-database>
  <jaxrs:server address="/">
    <jaxrs:providers>
      <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"/>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
      [other providers omitted]
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <bean class="foo.bar.UserService">
        <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        [...]
      </bean>
      [other service beans omitted]
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

"Integration Test":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:jaxrs-client="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs-client"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs-client http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs-client.xsd">
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        [...]
      </bean>
    </property>
    [...]
  </bean>
  [test classes omitted]
  <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"/>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
  <jaxrs:server address="local://api">
    <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
      [other providers omitted]
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <bean class="foo.bar.UserService"/>
      [other service beans omitted]
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>
  <jaxrs-client:client id="webClient" address="local://api" serviceClass="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient">
    <jaxrs-client:providers>
      <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs-client:providers>
    <jaxrs-client:headers>
      <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
    </jaxrs-client:headers>
  </jaxrs-client:client>
</beans>
```

Comment: There is no default no-args constructor and it cannot be created. Apparently you have an `context.xml` which wants this. So you are probably not loading that `context.xml` in your test and test something else.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My understanding is that implicit constructor injection can be used with any class that has a single non-default constructor. Each of the classes for which that exception is thrown has a single non-default constructor.

Comment: I am using a different context file for my integration tests. The only thing I've found that might make a difference between that context file and the "production" one is that the latter also has a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with a StandardServletEnvironment specified as its environment.

Comment: Unless you have something in your configuration that demands a no-arg constructor which appears to be so in this case. So either you aren't testing your configuration and have a separate test config or aren't testing this case. Simply put the error isn't wrong and the error is probably in your configuration.

Comment: The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` won't make a difference. If you are writing an integration test you should re-use the existing configuration and not create a special config for the integration test as you are now not testing the import part the actual configuration.

Comment: It seems like we're not using the term "integration test" the same way. What I'm calling "integration tests" you'd probably say are a kind of unit test. Regardless, I can provide the two context files (with sensitive information removed) for comparison later today.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Sorry for the delay, but I just added the context XML files.

Comment: Judging from the error message I would expect that the configs are the other way around. WIth that in mind it is logical that the error occurs as in your XML there is only `      <bean class="foo.bar.UserService"/>` which needs a default constructor. The implicit wiring you are talking about is only working with detected components and when annotation-config is enabled. Neither is. You might try and use `<context:annotation-config />` to enable annotation processing, but I doubt it will help in this case. Finally you really shouldn't be using 2 different configs, re-use the existing one.